# #Error in DLookup Function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using a function in MS Access to return a Query field value with a DLookup.  The function passes a value to `strPersonType` from an existing field in the query.

The function works fine when there is a value present in that field, however when there is no value present it returns `#Error`. In that case I would like it to return a `Null` or blank value.

I have tried error handling and `If` statements (like the one below) and I have been unable to fix it thus far.

No matter what I try the field value comes up as `#Error`.

```
Function LookUpPersonType2(strPersonType As String)            
    'Used to look up Person Type2 in the "Person Type Key" table given PERSON_TYPE
    'Returns original supplied name if no variation


    If IsNull(strPersonType) Or strPersonType = "" Then
        LookUpPersonType2 = ""
    Else

        If IsNull(DLookup("[Person Type2]", "[Person Type Key]", "[PERSON_TYPE] ='" & strPersonType & "'")) Then
            LookUpPersonType2 = strPersonType
        Else
            LookUpPersonType2 = DLookup("[Person Type2]", "[Person Type Key]", "[PERSON_TYPE] ='" & strPersonType & "'")
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print LookUpPersonType2 & ","
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried the `NZ` function? As `LookUpPersonType2=NZ(DLOOKUP(...) , NULL)`

Comment: Hey Darren, tried it.  Still getting the #Error issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I needed to change the passed parameter to a Variant variable type since there is a possibility that the value will be NULL.  Originally it was string variable type and strings cannot be NULL.  Thanks!